# I want to show roles related to users in selection option using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, user-permissions, laravel-permission

I am trying to show `roles` which is related to `user` but unfortunately  `userRoles` are not showing related to user in selection option, please help me how can I match that thanks.

Note :- I am using `spaite laravel permission` docs

**controller**

```
public function edit(User $user)
    {

        $data = [

            'isEdit' => true,
            'user' => $user,
            'roles' => Role::where('guard_name', '=', 'web')->select(['id', 'name'])->get(),

            'userRole' => $user->getRoleNames(),                 
              // i am getting userRole in array related to user
             //  ['employe']

        ];
        // return $data['userRole'];
        return view('cms.user_management.add-user', $data);
    }
```

**html view**

```
                     <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label>Role <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="roles[]">
                                    <option selected="selected" disabled >please 
                                   select</option>
                                    @foreach ($roles as $item)
                                   <option value="{{ $item->name }}"{{ $userRole == 
                                $item->name ? ' selected' : '' }}>{{ $item->name }}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('roles') ?? null }} 
                           </span>
                          </div>
```

Comment: what error you are getting have you dd the roles ?

Comment: Are you getting `userRole` as array or string?

Comment: after return userRoles  please check https://ibb.co/hVd1k1C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following changes in your HTML
If `$userRole` is array than check if $item->name exists in array, using `in_array`.

```
 'userRole' => $user->getRoleNames()->toArray(),
```

**html view**

```
{{ in_array($item->name, $userRole) ? 'selected' : '' }}


<div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="form-group">
          <label>Role<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
              <select class="form-control" name="roles[]">
                  <option selected="selected" disabled>please select</option>
                       @foreach ($roles as $item)
                             <option value="{{ $item->name }}"{{ in_array($item->name,$userRole) ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $item->name }}</option>
                       @endforeach
               </select>
       </div>
   <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('roles') ?? null }}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: sir i am getting error how can i resolve this please check it https://flareapp.io/share/OmVNwY8m

Comment: Can you show what are you getting in `userRole`?

Comment: after return userRoles please check link here   https://ibb.co/hVd1k1C

Comment: please check sir i am getting same error https://flareapp.io/share/67OkwpA7

Comment: @zubairmalik userRoles should be an array you are giving an object . 'userRole' => Auth::user()->roles->pluck('name'); use this method to get roles name

Comment: please why are you using Auth i thing it should be not used

Comment: Can you test by using static array `['employee']` instead of `$userRole`. Just want to check if you get error?

Comment: it's working perfectly after this query  'userRole' => $user->getRoleNames()->toArray(),

Comment: Good I was wondering if `userRole` was already an array.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this to get the roles asssociated with current user or

```
Auth::user()->roles->pluck('name');
```

for any specific user roles.

```
User::find($id)->roles->pluck('name')
```

Answer (score 1):

use Like this:-

```
$user->getRoleNames()->first(),
```